# Converting characters in a string swift

Tags: string, parsing, swift, ios8, character

I need to convert specific characters in a string (spaces and hyphens) to other specific characters (I will probably use an integer). I'm using a program that sends a user's location to Parse, and I need the class name to be the location, but it can't build class names with special characters or spaces.

Comment: Please provide some example on whats your input and what should be the result. Currently it is unclear what exactly are you asking.

Comment: An example input would have been "San Francisco", or "Burton-on-Trent", which needed outputs of "San1Francisco", and "Burton2On2Trent" respectively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension String {
    func exclude(excludeIt: String) -> String {
        return "".join(componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: excludeIt)))
    }
    func replaceAll(find:String, with:String) -> String {
        return stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(find, withString: with, options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    }
}


let helloWorld = "- -Hello - - -Wor ;ld:".exclude(" -:;")   // "HelloWorld"
let myReplacedString = "- -Hello - - -Wor ld".replaceAll(" ", with: "*").replaceAll("-", with: "|")   // "|*|Hello*|*|*|Wor*ld"
```